# why does this binary search succeed a return value in the middle is ignored?

Tags: java, return-value

I am still confused about the Binary Tree maximum path sum(Leetcode 124). 
I found a simple and effective java solution but there is no variable get the return value of the function helper(). Why does it still work?

Here is the code:

```
 public class Solution {

    int max = 0;
    public int maxPathSum(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null) return 0;
        max = root.val;
        helper(root);
        return max;
    }
    public int helper(TreeNode node)
    {
        if(node == null) return 0;
        int left = helper(node.left);
        int right = helper(node.right);
        left = left > 0 ? left : 0;
        right = right > 0 ? right : 0;
        int curMax = node.val + left + right;
        max = Math.max(max, curMax);
        return node.val + Math.max(left, right);
    }
}
```

In the "maxPathSum()" function, the third line, where is the return value of  "helper(root)"? (The definition of helper() below has a return statement. )

Comment: well, it's returning, you're just not using it, why shouldn't it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the concept of a Java method returning a value, and the obligation to use that returned value in the code which calls that method.  Even though `helper()` does return a value, there is no contract which says you must do the same when you call it.  So when you call

```
helper(root)
```

The return value will not be used in the method which called it.  To be clear, calling `helper(root)` does *not* mean that you will return from executing in the current calling method.

Comment: In addition, the algorithm can work because the class global max contains a value re-used in the maxPathSum method

Comment: Thank you very much! I see. So we just use the return value in the recursion process in the function helper. But in the maxPathSum, we only need to use the global variable max. So it is allowed that no variable to store the return value of helper(). All right, thank you!